# Безопасная и быстрая передача объектов между приложениями (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, сериализация

Есть две программы, которые должны передавать друг-другу экземпляры классов. Как реализовать передачу объектов между приложениями без создания сущностный в базе данных? Объекты сериализовать в файл не получается, некоторые объекты классов не помечены как Serializable. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ получить объект из кучи одного приложения другим или сериализовать его в файл без Serializable?

Comment: Объекты сильно сложные? Сериализация в `XML`/`JSON` не подойдет?

Comment: @Андрей объекты сложные. В них есть объекты, которые содержат другие объекты, которые в свою очередь тоже содержат объекты. Подскажите пожалуйста, а объект можно сериализовать в JSON какими-то автоматическими средствами? На то чтобы сделать структура JSON, аналогичную объекту, который нужно передать, вручную уйдет много времени.

Comment: Память машины общая? Или идет сетевое соединение?

Comment: @Vitalii общая. Но хотелось бы знать метод передачи объектов и при сетевом соединение.

Comment: Если общая, то можно покопать в marshal by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640280/marshal-by-bleed-reference-value
Если сетевое то попробовать Newtonsoft.JSON
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: То, что вам нужно, называется сериализацией. Она существует в миллионе вариантов. Нет, полностью автоматической сериализации не бывает, для сложных структур данных готовьтесь к сложностям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае работы с простыми типами, ты можешь использовать [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx). Это очень тяжеловестное и неповоротливое решение. В случае большого числа типов необходимо сгенерировать сборку сериализаторов, в противном случае при каждом запуске будет генерироваться виртуальная сборка.

Или же ты можешь написать собственный механизм сериализации. В целом, всё достаточно просто. При помощи Refelection ты перебираешь все члены класса, которые необходимо сериализовать - поля, свойства с backingFiled (надеюсь, тебе не придёт в голову передавать между приложениями обработчики событий). После этого вручную сериализуешь данные, сохраняя необходимую информацию для восстановления (если ты знаешь какой объект десериализуешь, а версия клиента и сервера оперирует типами с одинаковым набором полей и свойств, не требуя совместимости между разными версиями, то хранить ничего не потребуется, если ты не знаешь даже какой объект тебе приходит, придётся сохранять полное имя типа).

Напиши вначале тест, который сериализует и десериализует объект, и проверяет их на равенство. После этого принимайся за реализацию, время от времени прогоняя тест и устраняя косяки.

В самом грубом варианте, когда всё происходит при помощи Reflection, объекты создаются Activator'ом, и т.д. это не сложно. Дальше последуют оптимизации. Кэширование повторяющихся данных в графе объекта. Замена Reflection на предкомпилированные лямбда-выражения из Expression или голого IL-кода. Но тут уже всё зависит от требований к системе и объема передаваемых данных. Опытный разработчик напишет за месяц не напрягаясь.

Ещё одна альтернатива - это генерация кода сериализатора. Если типов много - генерируем кучу классов, компилируем, и используем при необходимости. Ничего хорошего в мире кодогенерации сейчас нет, наиболее свежие инструменты из набора Roslyn очень неудобны с общении. Проще написать самому.

Ну и, наконец, если типов не много, то в чём вопрос? Пишем вручную сериализатор для каждого из них и используем по мере необходимости. Можешь хоть Extension-методами для BinaryWriter/Reader'а сделать.

Отдельно стоит упомянуть вариант, который я бы не стал тащить в продакшен, но он тоже имеет право на жизнь. Это создание объектов вне управляемой кучи и, соответственно, передача их между границами приложений. Если порыться, можно найти подходящую статью. Но во-первых это не будет работать, если приложения разъедутся по разным машинам, а во-вторых ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет. Такую архитектуру придётся долго отлаживать и всё равно она будет радовать периодическими падениями с корапченой кучей где-нибудь на сборке мусора. Даже думать в этом направлении стоит на свой страх и риск.

Ну, а если всё-таки есть возможность модифицировать код, то в интернете [полно](https://habrahabr.ru/post/119503/) примеров автоматической сериализации и готовых решений, завязанных на развешанные атрибуты.